# How do I Use Count Function for different values of the same column in MS-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

For DB `StudentInfo` and Table `Student` as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
     ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
     Name nvarchar(255)
)
```

and inserting values:

```
Insert Into Student Values ('Ashok')`
```

executing it 3 times, and

```
Insert Into Student Values ('Achyut')
```

executing it 2 times and total 5 rows of data are inserted into the table.

I want to display a result counting the result with the name having 'Ashok' & 'Achyut'.

Generally for single values count in a column I use:

```
 SELECT Count(Name) AS NoOfStudentHavingNameAshok 
 FROM Student
 WHERE Name = 'Ashok'
```

but how to display the `NoOfStudentHavingNameAshok` & `NoOfStudentHavingNameAchyut` what query should I run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put conditions inside your `COUNT()` function:

```
select count(case when Name = 'Ashok' then 'X' end) as NoOfStudentHavingNameAshok,
       count(case when Name = 'Achyut' then 'X' end) as NoOfStudentHavingNameAchyut
  from Student
```

Answer (score 4):

You should include `name` in the `select` and `group by` `name`.

```
SELECT name, Count(*) 
From Student
group by name
```

Comment: This is the better way to do it. To OP: don't put data into column names (pivot) unless you *absolutely have to*. Use rows instead!

Comment: Thanks, it works but i want to display count only using two columns like NoOfAshok and NoOfAchyut.

Comment: sstan's answer does that